# Facebook app as page tab - login redirects to actual website rather than the page tab

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a simple Facebook app and added it as a tab page.  There is a login button on the page which works, however it redirects to the actual website.  I would like the user to be returned to that tab once they have logged in.  Is this possible?

**URL**: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Duaworld-Third-Vision/202611989828272?sk=app_278389335561559
**SDK**: PHP

Appreciate the help,
Jaap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your redirect URL to something on your site-domain, so it matches the app settings in Facebook and have that URL just issue a 301/302 redirect to send them to the Facebook fan page.

Comment: That's the fallback that I thought off as well. I just thought there might be a nicer way of doing it that I missed.  Cheers, mate.